# how to use the same offset for a consumer after Rebalance is done

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am beginner in Kafka and trying to understand a hypothetical case . If in case i have a

> partition P1 with consumer C1 (Consumer grp cg1) = commit offset as 30
>
> and
> Partition P2 with consumer C2 (Consumer grp cg1)  = commit offset as 40

Now rebalance happens and i want my consumer groups to carry there commit offsets to new partitions like :

> Partition P1 with consumer C2 (Consumer grp cg1) = commit offset as 40
>
> and P2 with consumer C1 (Consumer grp cg1)  = commit offset as 30

How can i achieve this ? can I use ConsumerRebalancerListener here or is there any other way out ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consumers "C1" and "C2" have no relation to offset values. More specifically, the ordering of assignment is not guaranteed, so referencing them by number is unclear.

When the group rebalances, then you're stuck with whatever offsets the group has committed for those offsets. Partition high-watermarks are unique. There is no guarantee partition 2 has offset 40 if partition 1 does.

You'd have to manually track "consumer names/IDs" outside of Kafka, then use `seek` method to get specific consumers to start at specific offsets after the partition assignment happens.

Ideally, you don't design your consumers like this. You'd be rewinding partition 2 by 10 offsets and re-processing that data. Meanwhile, skipping 10 offsets of partition 1 (which may not exist yet)...